# legacy database: Many-To-One/refrences without all needed keycolumns

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class referencing a (template)text which has for each tenant and each use case several possible texts

```
class Class1
{
    [...]
    public virtual Text TitleName { get; set; }
}

class Text
{
    public virtual int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Key { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunatly the tablestructure looks like

```
Table Class1
    ...
    textnumber int,

Table Text
    tenant int,
    key varchar (10),
    number int,
pkey(tenant, key, number);
```

because Class1 always refers to tenant = 0 (all tenants) and key = "class1text"

Edit:
i need .Where() but References() doenst have it only HasMany()

What i have so far:

```
public void TextMap : ClassMap<Text>
{
    public TextMap()
    {
       Table("restexts");

       CompositeId()
           .KeyProperty(t => t.TenantId, "tenant")
           .KeyProperty(t => t.Key, "name")
           .KeyProperty(t => t.Number, "number");

       Map(t => t.Value, "content");
    }
}

public void Class1Map : ClassMap<Class1>
{
    public TextMap()
    {
       // mapping rest

       References(c => c.TitleName)
           .Columns("textnumber", ??, ??);  // column 2 and 3 missing, because always the same
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: running out of time i mapped it like 
   Map(c => c.TitleNameId, "textnumber");
and have to remember the tenant and key name everytime i need the titlename (which is using magic values). I leave this open, if someone comes up with a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running out of time i mapped it like `Map(c => c.TitleNameId, "textnumber");` and have to remember the tenant and key name everytime i need the titlename (which is using magic values :(

Answer (score 0):

you can map your classes in this way with FluentNHibernate, it's a workaround to map only one field in OneToMany relationship.

```
public Class1()
{
 Table("TableName");
 Id(x => x.MyId).Column("TableId");
 .
 .
 .
 HasMany<TextModel>(x => x.textnumber).KeyColumn("TableField");
}

public Text()
{
 Table("TableName");
 Id(x => x.MyId).Column("TableId");
 .
 .
 .
 References<Class1Model>(x => x.number,"TableColumn");
}
```

Then you can add in your query the filters on the other fields (tenent = 0 and key = "class1text")

I hope it's helpful

Comment: thx for the answer. When i only map number as primary key, I get duplicate key exception if i try to insert more than one text for a given key because number isn't identity any more :/

Comment: Try try to use CompositeId() method inside the map class;  CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.ID, "TableId1").KeyReference(x => x.ID2, "TableId2"); here an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121651/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-a-compositeid-and-querying-with-setprojection

Comment: thx for the info, but i know that already. i have mapped Text as CompositeId() but i cant think of a way to map the reference from Class1 to Text, because the Table of Class1 doesnt repeat all keycolumns from Text